# Using a function to cast bigint to timestamp

Tags: postgresql, function, casting

I have 2 values: x_data and y_data.
These values are the X and Y of a graph.

x_data is currently a epoch value multiplied for 1000, my function should be able to divide it by 1000 and cast to timestamp for inserting in the corresponding table.

This is what I've got so far, obviously not working:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE test set x_data=ceil(in_x_data/1000)::abstime::timestamp, y_data=in_y_data WHERE x_data=ceil(in_x_data/1000)::abstime::timestamp;
 IF FOUND THEN 
  RETURN;
 END IF;
 BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO test ( x_data, y_data ) VALUES ( ceil(in_x_data/1000)::abstime::timestamp, in_y_data );
 END;
RETURN;
END;

ERROR: ERROR:  cannot cast type double precision to abstime
```

I tried to `ceil(in_x_data::NUMERIC/1000)::abstime::timestamp` but `cannot cast type numeric to abstime`

This is how I call the function:

```
SELECT test(1538949600000,123);
```

Table test is:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    x_data timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    y_data numeric,
    PRIMARY KEY (x_data)
)
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I guess I fixed it.. `select ceil(1538949600000/1000)::integer::abstime::timestamp;`

Comment: to_timestamp() function might work

Comment: indeed! `select to_char(to_timestamp(ceil(1538949600000/1000)), 'YYYY-MM-DD');`